# Why is this Groovy closure not returning the value that I expect?

Tags: grails, groovy

In a Grails application, I am trying to prevent the creation of cycles in a directed graph. The user is able to assign a parent to a node, but no node should be its own parent's ancestor. I have written a simple setup function that calls checkLineageForTarget, which is the recursive function that does the heavy lifting:

```
boolean checkLineageForTarget(Integer target, Collection<Node>stillToProcess){
// true means that this is a safe addition
// false means that this addition creates a cycle

    boolean retVal = stillToProcess.each {
        Collection<Node> itsParents = getParentNodes(it)

        if (it.id == target){
            println("found a loop on " + target);
            return false; // loop detected!
        }
        if (itsParents.empty){ return true; } // end of the line

        return checkLineageForTarget(target, itsParents)
    }

    // at this point, retVal is always true, even when the "found a loop [...]" condition is met
    return retVal;
}
```

This "works," in that it prints the "found a loop [...]" message, but outside of the closure, retVal is true, the calling function attempts to add the new parent/child relationship, and my stack runneth over.

What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: can you use `.each` like that? i'd be using `.every`

Comment: It's Grails, not "Groovy on Grails"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`each`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#each%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method returns the same collection it was invoked on, so `retVal` is probably not the boolean "true", but is evaluated as "truthly" (as it is a collection, it would mean it's not empty).

If you want to check a condition for every element in a collection, you might use [`every`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#every%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

```
boolean checkLineageForTarget(Integer target, Collection<Node>stillToProcess){
    stillToProcess.every { node ->
        node.id != target && checkLineageForTarget(target, getParentNodes(node))
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't need check the `.empty` condition on the parent nodes collection because that will be filtered by the recursive call to checkLineageForTarget (i.e. calling `.every` on an empty collection always returns true). Also, because of the short-circuiting of the `&&` operator, the iteration stops as soon as `node.id == target` :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a big improvement.

Answer (score 3):

`.each` appears to return the Object being looped over when it is done. You are assign this to a boolean and it is being coerced to `true`. You probably want to use `.every` for your task. It returns `true` only if each iteration returns `true` and it will stop looping when it hits the first `false`. You can find more information [in the groovy docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you return inside a Closure, it's like returning inside a method call within the method - it's local to that scope and has no impact on the real method the closure is being called in. In this case you can use one of the other approaches suggested (e.g. every) or use a regular for loop since it works the same as the Groovy each (i.e. it's null-safe and supports but doesn't require types) but you can break out of the loop or return and since you're in a real for loop it will return from the method:

```
boolean checkLineageForTarget(Integer target, Collection<Node>stillToProcess){

   for (Node node in stillToProcess) {
      Collection<Node> itsParents = getParentNodes(node)
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```